# Android onClick in XML vs. OnClickListener

Tags: android, xml, performance, android-fragments

I realize that a similarly-worded question has been asked before, but this is different. I am pretty new at developing android apps and I have three questions regarding the difference(s) between the `android:onclick=""` XML attribute and the `setOnClickListener` method.

1. What are the differences between the two? Is the difference between the two implementations found at compile time or run time or both?
2. What use cases are favorable to which implementation?
3. What difference(s) does the use of fragments in Android make in implementation choice?

Comment: For #2: You should be careful when using the xml `onclick` as you need to ensure that every class implements that method.  This is assuming that you are using the layout more than once.  However, if you were to have a java interface to ensure the method was in all classes that implemented it, you wouldn't have to worry.

Comment: Wouldn't having a java interface as you described be pretty much the same as extending or implimenting OnClickListener?

Comment: I've looked into this before and I think there's a little bit more to it than preference, but I'm sorry I can't say much more as it's been a while.  I like the `android:onclick` when it's convenient, but I know that sometimes it has caused issues, and I can't remember those either :)

Comment: xml onClick doesn't work for nested layout elements which are dynamically inflated in API level 19

Comment: I have rarely seen code from other people implementing android:onClick and it is the most confusing when you look through someone elses code. As it has not all possibilities of setOnClickListener nearly everbody uses only setOnClickListener in my opinion

Answer (score 129, accepted):

**Difference Between OnClickListener vs OnClick:**

- OnClickListener is the interface you need to implement and can be set
  to a view in java code.
- OnClickListener is what waits for someone
  to actually click, onclick determines what happens when someone
  clicks.
- Lately android added a xml attribute to views called android:onclick,
  that can be used to handle clicks directly in the view's activity
  without need to implement any interface.
- You could easily swap one listener implementation with another if you need to.
- An OnClickListener enable you to separate the action/behavior of the click event from the View that triggers the event. While for simple cases this is not such a big deal, for complex event handling, this could mean better readability and maintainability of the code
- Since OnClickListener is an interface, the class that implements it has flexibilities in determining the instance variables and methods that it needs in order to handle the event. Again, this is not a big deal in simple cases, but for complex cases, we don't want to necessary mix up the variables/methods that related to event handling with the code of the View that triggers the event.
- The onClick with function binding in XML Layout is a binding between onClick and the function that it will call. The function have to have one argument (the View) in order for onClick to function.

Both function the same way, just that one gets set through java code and the other through xml code.

**setOnClickListener Code Implementation:**

```java
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    myFancyMethod(v);
    }
});

// some more code

public void myFancyMethod(View v) {
    // does something very interesting
}
```

**XML Implementation:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- layout elements -->
<Button android:id="@+id/mybutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click me!"
    android:onClick="myFancyMethod" />
<!-- even more layout elements -->
```

**Performance:**

Both are the same in performance. Xml is pre-parsed into binary code while compiling. so there is no over-head in Xml.

**Limitation:**

android:onClick is for API level 4 onwards, so if you're targeting < 1.6, then you can't use it.

Comment: ` Xml is pre-parsed into binary code while compiling`  What does this statement means exactly? Since I have seen the dexcode of an apk which has android:onClick in its manifest file, but I did not find any code that explicitly **set the listener**

Comment: Actually, there is some overhead in _XML_. When the button is clicked for the first time, [_reflection_ is used to determine the method that should be invoked](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#L4703). However, this is probably negligible for most use-cases (and premature optimization is the root of all evil).

Answer (score 24):

I'm shocked nobody talked about this but be careful, although `android:onClick` XML seems to be a convenient way to handle click, the `setOnClickListener` implementation do something additional than adding the `onClickListener`. Indeed, it put the view property `clickable` to true.

While it's might not be a problem on most Android implementations, according to the phone constructor, button is always default to clickable = true but other constructors on some phone model might have a default clickable = false on non Button views.

So setting the XML is not enough, you have to think all the time to add `android:clickable="true"` on non button, and if you have a device where the default is clickable = true and you forget even once to put this XML attribute, you won't notice the problem at runtime but will get the feedback on the market when it will be in the hands of your customers !

In addition, we can never be sure about how proguard will obfuscate and rename XML attributes and class method, so not 100% safe that they will never have a bug one day.

So if you never want to have trouble and never think about it, it's better to use `setOnClickListener` or libraries like ButterKnife with annotation `@OnClick(R.id.button)`

Comment: Did you have any experience (or seen somewhere) that bug occurred due to obfuscation when using `android:onClick`?

Comment: Thank you, sir! Your answer is very helpful!

Answer (score 13):

Simply:

If you have `android:onClick = "someMethod"` **in xml**, it looks for the `public void someMethod` in your Activity class. `OnClickListener` is called right **from your Activity** and it is linked to some particular `View`. For example `someButton.setOnClickListener` and in the code below is said what has to be done when `someButton` is pressed.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 4):

As said before: they both are a way to add logic in response to an event, in this case a 'click' event.

I would go for a separation between logic and presentation, just like we do in the  HTML/JavaScript world: Leave the XML for presentation and add event listeners by means of code.

Comment: Agreed, unless it's a very tiny app with some simple behavior, all of your executing code should be kept separate and well organized, preferably using separate methods

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of reasons why you might want to programmatically set an `OnClickListener`. The first is if you ever want to change the behaviour of your button while your app is running. You can point your button at another method entirely, or just disable the button by setting an `OnClickListener` that doesn't do anything.

When you define a listener using the `onClick` attribute, the view looks for a method with that name only in its host activity. Programmatically setting an `OnClickListener` allows you to control a button's behaviour from somewhere other than its host activity. This will become very relevant when we use `Fragments`, which are basically mini activities, allowing you to build reusable collections of views with their own lifecycle, which can then be assembled into activities. Fragments always need to use `OnClickListeners` to control their buttons, since they're not Activities, and won't be searched for listeners defined in onClick.

Answer (score 0):

If you have several buttons using only one method, I suggest doing it in java. But if you have a button with one specific method, onClick in XML would be better.

Answer (score 0):

It's more convenient to always use android:onClick attribute unless you have a good reason not to, for example, if you instantiate the Button at runtime or you need to declare the click behavior in a Fragment subclass.

Comment: I have rarely seen code from other people implementing android:onClick and it is the most confusing when you look through someone elses code. As it has not all possibilities of setOnClickListener nearly everbody uses only setOnClickListener in my opinion

Answer (score -1):

I think main difference between them is:

OnClick: When you click on the button with your finger.

OnClickListner: It is may be a wider choice that be implemented in various codes.

For example when you type url "ymail.com", yahoo finds your username and your password from your browser and enable click state button to open your mail. This action should be implemented only in onClickListener.

This is my idea!

Comment: This is interesting but there is much more than that; yours should had rather be a comment.