# What are the differences in using onClick in the xml and button.setOnClickListener in the activity?

Tags: android, performance

As far as I can tell, there are two ways to implement a button click in android. One is by defining `android:onClick="someFunction"` and another is by having a listener in the activity. What I want to know is:

1. Are they the same and if I can use them interchangeably.
2. Are there things I can do with one and not the other? Any limitations?
3. Is it just up to opinion which is better practice?

Comment: They are the same.

Comment: Both works the same way and its totally your choice which way you want to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One is by defining android:onClick="someFunction" and another is by having a listener in the activity.

Not exactly. Your choices are:

1. Use `android:onClick`, pointing to a method in the activity that hosts this widget, using the native implementation of this (what we have had since Android 1.6)
2. Call `setOnClickListener()` on the `View`, passing in an implementation of an `OnClickListener`
3. Use the data binding framework to [tie `android:onClick` to an arbitrary method or an arbitrary lambda expression](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#event_handling)

> Are they the same and if I can use them interchangeably.

They are the same, insofar as both define behaviors to be invoked if the user clicks the widget.

> Are there things I can do with one and not the other? Any limitations?

Option #1 is limited to methods implemented on the hosting activity. Option #2 and Option #3 are not. With those, you can implement the logic to be invoked on a click event as part of some UI controller or presenter, such as a fragment.

> Is it just up to opinion which is better practice?

Well, pretty much everything is up to opinion.

IMHO, Option #1 is fine for trivial apps, such as book examples. Option #3 is new but powerful, and I anticipate that this will be the long-term solution.

Answer (score 0):

android:onclick can be used to handle clicks directly in the view's activity without need to implement any interface.

android:onClick is for API level 4 onward, so if you're targeting < 1.6, then you can't use it.

An OnClickListener enables you to separate the action of the click event from the View that triggers the event.

You can refer this thread for more details [Android onClick in XML vs. OnClickListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319996/android-onclick-in-xml-vs-onclicklistener)

Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah, I saw that link before but it didn't really answer all my questions plus it was written 2 years ago so I was wondering if anything had changed since then.