# Android - make a button display a value on screen and playing sound correctly

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm doing the Udacity's android beginner course (even thou I'm not beginner to programming) and decided to fool around a little.

I've managed to make a button either change the value on screen (by adding +1 value) or to play a sound, but when I mix both, the button only plays the sound, but does not add a number / update the value on screen, anyone knows why?

I have three methods; 1 for calling the mediaPlayer:

```java
   // This method calls mediaPlayer
public void mediaPlayer (String sound, String id){
    Uri uriPlayer = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/" + sound );
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, uriPlayer);

    int playIdInt = getResources().getIdentifier(id, "id", getPackageName());
    Button play_button = (Button)this.findViewById(playIdInt);
    play_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
}
```

2. For displaying the value on screen

   ```
   /**
   * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
   */
    private void display(int number) {
   TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
   quantityTextView.setText("" + number);
   ```
3. For adding +1 value to the variable, calling the display method and the media player method:

```java
    public void increment (View view){
    quantity = quantity + 1;
    display(quantity);
    mediaPlayer("mariocoin", "plus_button");
}
```

EDIT: not sure if needed, but here is XML of the button:

```xml
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/plus_button"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:onClick="increment"
        android:text="+" />
```

The thing is that when I play the button the first time, it adds 1 and display on the screen, but no sound played. The second and subsequent times it only plays the sound. It does not add +1 to the variable nor change the value on screen. Why and how can I fix this?

Comment: where do you start the quantity variable?

Comment: @Richard = I'm not sure I understood what you meant. The XML code for the button calls the 1.method: increment that calls both 2.method: display and 3.method: mediaPlayer

Comment: the quantity variable is global  with initial value of 0 right?

Comment: @Tiago: all those methods are inside public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { }. | The quantity is the first thing declared as global variable (int quantity = 0;) after the first method:     ---@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }

Comment: playIdInt is = to plus_button?

Comment: Hey Tiago, thanks for the attention, Varad bellow had the solution!

Comment: @mrbTT I think your XML edit helped, and Varad explained what I was trying to get my head around. I just saw your first click listener that didn't do anything other than play the sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have define two ClickListeners for same button. The first one calls increment method and the second one is defined inside media player method. That listener is not required.

```
//Somewhere in oncreate .. Not required if xml has onclick specified
Button play_button = (Button)this.findViewById(playIdInt);
play_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       increment();
    }
});


public void increment (View view){
       quantity = quantity + 1;
       display(quantity);
       mediaPlayer("mariocoin", "plus_button");
}

// This method calls mediaPlayer
public void mediaPlayer (String sound, String id){
            Uri uriPlayer = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/" + sound );
            final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, uriPlayer);
            mp.start();
        }
```

Comment: This is exactly it, thank you very much!! Just another question: So it's a best practice to create the play_button inside the onCreate? Also, I didn't add your line of "public void onClick(View v)" inside the onCreate method, is that necessary?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319996/android-onclick-in-xml-vs-onclicklistener