# Navigation drawer: how to make the item direct you to a website. Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigation-drawer, onitemselectedlistener

Hi guys perfect saturday for some coding :)

I have a navigation drawer where i can click on items and they direct me to fragments. But how i make so when i press an item in the navigation drawer to link me to a website. I'm not really good at items..

I will post three different imgur images  [See the 3 images here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiXnq.jpg)
So when you press it, example: www.google.com comes up in your regular "chrome app" i'm not really interested in webview cause of the website is not html5.

This is my MainActivity at the bottom of it you can find how i use the items for my fragments.

I'm a rookie programmer hehe... But it is so fun! Learning step by step.

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity


        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
//TextView tstnr;
    TextView radertst;

    Button sendSMSaon;
    EditText aonTxt;
    //TextView nrladd;








    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


       // tstnr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nummertestsp);
        radertst = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.raderanumtxt);

        sendSMSaon = (Button)findViewById(R.id.skickaaon);
        aonTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.aon);
     //  nrladd = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.numretladd);


    }
//This is where the call for the value in the setttings are.
//Här är så att man kan lägga in values från inställningar till mainactivity.

    public void displayData(View view){

        SharedPreferences prefs =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String name = prefs.getString("example_text", "");
   radertst.setText(name + " ");
    }

//downbelow is where the onresume so the value boots up with the app.
//nedanför är för att appen ska ladda koden i settings direkt när man startar

   @Override
    protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
      SharedPreferences prefs =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        String name = prefs.getString("example_text", "");
       radertst.setText(name + " ");}



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);



            return true;
        }




        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();


        if (id == R.id.nav_first_layout) {

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame
                    , new FirstFragment())
                    .commit();
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_second_layout) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame
                            , new SecondFragment())
                    .commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_third_layout) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame
                            , new ThirdFragment())
                    .commit();




        }




        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;








}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this on your menu item

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

so on your onNavigationItemSelected you have to add another if and search for the id of the item you need:

I made an example

```
     @Override
     public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            return true;
        }

        else if (id == R.id.YOUR_ITEM_ID) {
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);

            return true;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked really fine! you really navigated me there *pun* ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this in your `onClick` method of a button, or listener, however you wanna handle the click event:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
                Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/"));
startActivity(intent);
```

If you don't know how to handle the click itself [check this out.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319996/android-onclick-in-xml-vs-onclicklistener), but I see in your code that you can, so it's fine.