# Subscribing to events in Android. XML attribute vs code onClickListener

Tags: java, android, xml, events, onclicklistener

Could please someone explain pros and cons of subscribing to events, xml vs code approaches?

I suppose there should be some guidelines on that topic, but I can't imagine an use-case where one will be better that another. Maybe some best practices, or recipes?

It would be great if you share your experience and knowledge. Maybe some examples?

Thanks.

Comment: I never use onClick in xml because when I change the method name in code, it will not change the name in xml

Comment: So you don't use the xml onClick just of code management / refactoring/ maintenance dependencies?

Comment: yes, but someone may have another style

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android onClick in XML vs. OnClickListener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319996/android-onclick-in-xml-vs-onclicklistener)