# returning id of a listview item by clicking on a button

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I want a custom listview in android studio that each item has a button. By clicking on this button it should return the id of the item in the listview that the button is in it to the main activity.
I had recently added the layout xmls and my only problem is in the MainActivity.java and the class that is needed in it.

Comment: What code have you already written to try and get your result? How is it not working yet?

Answer (score 0):

In the adapter's `getView` method set the button's tag e.g.:-

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {


        Button yourbutton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.yourbuttonid);
        yourbutton.setTag(position);
        .......
```

In the button's onClick handling use `int position = (int) view.getTag();` to retrieve the position which should correlate to the array's index.

There are two main ways of handling the button's `onClick` in a ListView

---

#### 1) specify the method to be used in the Button's XML (only since API level 4) and provide the handling method in the invoking activity:-

***Example XML :-***

```
<Button android:id="@+id/mybutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click"
    android:onClick="myButtonClicked" />
```

***Example handler in the activity that includes the respective ListView***

```
    .....
    public myButtonClicked(View view) {
        int position = (int) view.getTag();
        ....
    }
```

---

#### 2) Include setting the Listener and the `onCLick` handling in the `ListView`'s `adapter`'s `getView` method.

***Example :-***

```
        public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {

    
            Button yourbutton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.yourbuttonid);
            yourbutton.setTag(position);
            yourbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(View view) {
                   int position = view.getTag();
               }
            });
```

You may wish to have a look at these, which cover the above in more detail

- [Android onClick in XML vs. OnClickListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319996/android-onclick-in-xml-vs-onclicklistener)
- [Android : How to set onClick event for Button in List item of ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596199/android-how-to-set-onclick-event-for-button-in-list-item-of-listview)

*I personally find the XML method very convenient. I utilise a `Style` as the basis for the buttons (I use a TextView for the buttons) so have a single method (as set in the Style) that I just incorporate into the respective activities. This even copes admirably with multiple Buttons per ListView item.*

Comment: Where should I put button's onClick?

Comment: @M.R.Davoodi, answer updated to include where you can put the onClick handler.