# difference between android:onClick and onClickListener

Tags: android

I'm curious how these construction differ. One calls method on object (eg button) and passes anon function, and the other uses `android:onClick` property that we set in the layout file. So why should I use one method or the other. From the coding point of view listeners seem to give more control, am i right?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319996/android-onclick-in-xml-vs-onclicklistener) is a pretty good answer which points out the differences.

Comment: Check this answer here [Difference Between OnClickListener vs OnClick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21326604/4403813)