# OnClick method for a custom view has never called (Android)

Tags: android, data-binding, onclick, android-custom-view, android-databinding

I'm trying to use Custom view that extends `RelativeLayout` and named `CardView`. A added some attr and created XML file for them, everything work correct, except `onClick`. So, at first I've created a special class for my view:

```
class CardView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : RelativeLayout(context, attrs) {

init {
    inflate(context, R.layout.card_view, this)
    val imageView: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.image)
    val textView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.caption)
    val line: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.line)

    val attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CardView)
    imageView.setImageResource(attributes.getResourceId(R.styleable.CardView_image, 0))
    textView.text = attributes.getString(R.styleable.CardView_text)
    line.setBackgroundColor(attributes.getColor(R.styleable.CardView_lineColor, 0))
    attributes.recycle()
} }
```

I aslo have a xml file for my View:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="@dimen/cardSize"
android:layout_height="@dimen/cardSize"
android:background="@drawable/card_color_selector"
android:clickable="true">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="60sp"
    android:layout_height="60sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="3sp"
    tools:src="@color/colorPrimary" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/caption"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/text_normal"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="10sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/darkGray"
    tools:text="Caption" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/line"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And finally I've added my `customView` in activity layout with link to `onClick` method in view model like here:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.presentation.screen.HomeViewModel" />
</data>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.project.presentation.utils.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/cardSize"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/cardSize"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.onClick()}"
        app:image="@drawable/icon"
        app:lineColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:text="@string/text" />    

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

So everything is good, colors are changed as i'd written in `card_color_selector.xml`, but method `onClick` in my `ViewModel` has never called. Oh, by the way my view model is here, now I just want to logged all the clicks:

```
class HomeViewModel : BaseViewModel<Router>() {

    fun onClick() {
        Log.e("myLog", "HomeViewModel onClick")
    }
}
```

I've tried everything! Please help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I had a same problem.

Check your customview's clickable attribute!

If your child view in custom view is preventing touch event, your parent's

`android:onClick` will be ignored.

Comment: This answer is so underrated. It solved my problem. And I've been worrying about it for days

Answer (score 1):

Change you're `onClick` method like thisTry like this

```
fun onClick(view: View) {
        Log.d("myLog", "HomeViewModel onClick")
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have already tryed this way, it doesn't change anything :(

Comment: If you don't mind can I ask you one thing why you are using `Log.e` instead of Log.d or others?? Did you properly checked the log??

Comment: yes, because there are another logs in my app, so i haven't any problem with them.

Comment: that looks like i have to set onClickListener to my custom view, but in mvvm architecture i can't use anything like `findViewById`. That's why i'm truing to find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your

```
fun onClick() {
    Log.e("myLog", "HomeViewModel onClick")
}
```

pass `View` In XML section for

> onClick="method" you have to set parameter as `View` class in your method.

You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319996/android-onclick-in-xml-vs-onclicklistener)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so can you try

```
    android:onClick="@{(v) -> viewModel.onClick(v)}"
```

and for the function

```
     fun onClick(view:View) {
    Log.e("myLog", "HomeViewModel onClick")
     }
```

Comment: Yes, I've already tryed and i have no idea why doesn't it work. Could the problem be connected with attribute android:clickable="true" for layout in my Custom View?

Comment: May be, only way to know is to test it. remove both clickable true attribute and test it.
and make sure you have set value of homeViewModel.